# Why does this return -1 when I try to find .IndexOf(a) in the list?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop, indexof

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int charCount = 0;
        BigInteger a = 0;
        BigInteger b = 1;
        List<BigInteger> list = new List<BigInteger>();
        while(0 != 1)
        {
            list.Add(a);
            BigInteger c = a;   //
            a = b;              // this is the Fibonacci sequence
            b = a + c;          //
            charCount = a.ToString().Length;
            if (charCount >= 1000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(a));
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
}
}
```

This was written for problem 25 on project Euler, where you need to find the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence that contains 1000 digits.

I checked and the application works up until writing list.IndexOf(a). For some reason, it writes the index to be -1.

By using an integer i with i++ in the loop (shown below), I was able to solve the problem, but I am rather curious about why -1 is returned instead of the index.

```
int i = 0;
int charCount = 0;
BigInteger a = 0;
BigInteger b = 1;
while(0 != 1)
{
    i++;
    BigInteger c = a;
    a = b;
    b = a + c;
    charCount = a.ToString().Length;
    string thing = a.ToString();
    if (charCount >= 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.IndexOf(a) // returns -1 if 'a' could not be fount in 'list'
```

note that you changed 'a' after adding it to the list, so it's another value already when you use index of. This way it will work:

```
    while(0 != 1)
    {
        list.Add(a);
        charCount = a.ToString().Length;
        if (charCount >= 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(a));
            break;
        } 
        BigInteger c = a;   //
        a = b;              // this is the Fibonacci sequence
        b = a + c;          //
    }
```

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. Can't believe I missed that, thanks for clearing that up!